# Kendo UI (Editor) - On Click Link, Insert HTML

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-editor

I am using **Kendo UI - Editor**.

If I click on `Show Message` link, "**Click Success!**" message should appear inside Editor

I want to show Custom Text inside Editor on Clicking on "**Show Message**" link...

**Pleae Help !!!**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".importeditor").kendoEditor({
    tools: [
      "bold",
      {
        name: "custom",
        myText: "Show Message",
        template: $("#toolTemplate").html()
      },
    ]
  });
});

jQuery('#ClickMe').on('click', function () {
  jQuery(".importeditor").data('kendoEditor').val('Click Success!');
});
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.common-material.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/styles/kendo.material.min.css" />

<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<script src="//kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2015.3.1111/js/kendo.timezones.min.js"></script>

<div class="textedit1">
  <textarea rows="10" cols="45" name="textarea" class="txtarea importeditor"></textarea>
</div>

<script id="toolTemplate" type="text/x-kendo-template">
    <a href="\#" id="ClickMe">#= myText #</a>
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [value method](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/editor#methods-value) IE

```
  jQuery(".importeditor").data('kendoEditor').value('Click Success!');
```

Also you might want to fix your href in the a tag

```
<a href="\#" id="ClickMe">#= myText #</a>
```

Comment: **@Lazy Coder**..  already tried with No Luck :(.. Thanks for the Typo though

Comment: hmm works here https://jsfiddle.net/sjmn8dew/ maybe I don't understand the question?

Comment: Thanks **@Lazy Coder**.. in fiddle it is working great... but where as in my application it is throwing an error 'Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'value' of undefined'

Comment: Really sorry **@Lazy Coder**.. That was my bad... Typo again... :(... **It is working great** now... Thanks for your Time...  **I am Accepting Your Answer and also Voting Up** :).. You saved my day

Comment: Hi **@Lazy Coder**... There is one more thing about it, forgot to mention. I want to append text.. not to replace. For Example, if I have already some text inside, your code is replacing that as well... Any help please?

Comment: To append the text I think you could just call value() + ' text to append', so if put the text to a var  s = jQuery(".importeditor").data('kendoEditor').value(); then you should be able to pass that in to value like so jQuery(".importeditor").data('kendoEditor').value(s + ' new text to append')

Comment: Hi **@Lazy Coder**.. working like Charm... Thanks again